# backbone.js Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'View' of null

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, uncaught-exception

When I run my backbone app in NetBeans 7.3.1, the main page displays for a few seconds, maybe 5 or 6, then in NetBeans output I see the following...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'View' of null (18:43:36:307 | error, javascript)
    at  (js/views/HomeView.js:6:28)
    at d.execCb (js/libs/require/require.js:27:197)
    at o (js/libs/require/require.js:10:471)
    at  (js/libs/require/require.js:12:184)
    at o (js/libs/require/require.js:12:75)
    at  (js/libs/require/require.js:14:1)
    at o (js/libs/require/require.js:12:75)
    at l (js/libs/require/require.js:12:336)
    at g.finishLoad (js/text.js:10:192)
    at g.load (js/text.js:10:354)
    at window.undefined.window.navigator.window.document.c.onreadystatechange (js/text.js:7:30)
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Model' of null (18:43:36:317 | error, javascript)
    at  (js/models/Member.js:6:26)
    at d.execCb (js/libs/require/require.js:27:197)
    at o (js/libs/require/require.js:10:471)
    at x (js/libs/require/require.js:15:186)
    at m (js/libs/require/require.js:15:207)
    at g.completeLoad (js/libs/require/require.js:21:388)
    at d.onScriptLoad (js/libs/require/require.js:27:490)
Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: text!templates/homeTemplate.html 
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout (18:43:38:511 | error, javascript)
    at N (js/libs/require/require.js:7:217)
    at A (js/libs/require/require.js:16:230)
    at  (js/libs/require/require.js:16:394)
```

It looks like RequireJS is failing to load Backbone. Here is `main.js`...

```
// Filename: main.js

require.config({
    shim: {
        underscore: {
            exports: '_'
        },
        backbone: {
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        }
    },
    paths: {
        jquery: 'libs/jquery/jquery-min',
        underscore: 'libs/underscore/underscore-min',
        backbone: 'libs/backbone/backbone-min',
        templates: '../templates'
    }
});

require([
    'app',

], function(App) {
    App.initialize();
});
```

I'm totally spinning my wheels on this. Why is Require not loading Backbone?

@Sushanth--: Edited original post to include HomeView.js

Here is the HomeView.js...

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'text!templates/homeTemplate.html'
], function($, _, Backbone, homeTemplate) {

    var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: $("#page"),

        initialize: function() {
        },

        render: function() {
            var compiledTemplate = _.template( homeTemplate, {} );
            this.$el.html( compiledTemplate ); 
        }

    });

    return HomeView;

});
```

@Sushanth--: I'm rendering from the router.js...

```
// Filename: /js/router.js

define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'views/HomeView',
    'views/MembersView'
], function($, _, Backbone, HomeView, MembersView) {

  var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      // Define some URL routes
      'members': 'showMembers',
      // Default
      '*actions': 'defaultAction'
    }
  });

  var initialize = function(){
      //alert('router init');
    var app_router = new AppRouter;

    app_router.on('route:showMembers', function () {
        // Like above, call render but know that this view has nested sub views which 
        // handle loading and displaying data from the GitHub API  
        var membersView = new MembersView();
    });

    app_router.on('route:defaultAction', function (actions) {
        // We have no matching route, lets display the home page 
        var homeView = new HomeView();
        homeView.render();
    });

    // Unlike the above, we don't call render on this view as it will handle
    // the render call internally after it loads data. Further more we load it
    // outside of an on-route function to have it loaded no matter which page is
    // loaded initially.
    //var footerView = new FooterView();

    //alert('hello from router.js');
    //Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root: "/modular-backbone/"});
    //Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
    Backbone.history.start();
    };

    return { 
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

Added a test alert in main.js, app.initialize...

```
require(['app'], function(App) {
    // THIS ALERT NEVER DISPLAYS!?!?!
    alert('inside main.js before app.initialize');
    App.initialize();
});
```

Comment: Are you missing the `baseUrl` property ?

Comment: Where would this method go?

Comment: @Locohost.. It is not a method. It is a property of config file that tells require what the baseUrl of the files are supposed to be.. Check this http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-baseUrl

Comment: I added baseUrl to the require.config in main.js. I set it to a few different path values and am still getting the exact same error. Something else is missing.

Comment: How does your view look like that is throwing an error

Comment: @Sushanth-- Added my HomeView.js to OP.

Comment: cool.. Can you also paste the code inside `initialize` method where I believe you are rendering the view

Comment: @Sushanth-- I added the router.js to show the view render call. Also I added a section from my main.js. You can see the error note in the code above. That's the problem. The app is never initializing for some reason. What would cause this?

Comment: I used this tutorial to learn how to organize a backbone project: https://github.com/thomasdavis/backbonetutorials/tree/gh-pages/examples/modular-backbone

Comment: Have you declared this file in HTML `<script data-main="js/main" src="js/libs/require/require.js"></script>`. Also are you using the same folder structure that project follows

Comment: When you say, `require(['app'], ...)` in `main.js`, just check whether the `app` is declared in `require.config`, if I'm not wrong it should point to `router.js`.

Comment: @Cyclone: the `require(['app']...` line is supposed to load the app.js file which is in the same folder as main.js, then call it's App.initialize method. But for some reason now, that app require block is not executing. The test alert above shows me this. This is the startup up of the whole app. It's like turning the key in your car and nothing happens.

Comment: One suggestion, can you please change `require(['app'], ...)` to `require(['app.js'], ...)` and give it a try ?

Answer (score 1):

I replaced my Backbone and Underscore js files with the AMD versions and it started working.